# How to double click in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, playwright

I have a workspace in which I can add different objects. There is a scenario in which on double click, an object can be automatically added in the workspace. I have gone through different solutions but none of them really worked.

This is what I have tried:

```
await page.evaluate(selector => {
  var targLink = document.querySelector(selector);
  var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  clickEvent.initEvent('dblclick', true, true);
  targLink.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}, selector)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`mouse.click(x, y[, options])`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#mouseclickx-y-options).

---

First get `x` and `y`.

```
const selector = "#elementID";

const rect = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (!element) return null;
  const { x, y } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { x, y };
}, selector);
```

Then pass `clickCount` as an option to simulate double click.

```
await page.mouse.click(rect.x, rect.y, { clickCount: 2 });
```

---

**Full code:**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://www.example.com", {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  });

  const selector = "#elementID";

  const rect = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (!element) return null;
    const { x, y } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { x, y };
  }, selector);

  if (rect) {
    await page.mouse.click(rect.x, rect.y, { clickCount: 2 });
  } else {
    console.error("Element Not Found");
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

---

**Update**

You can add delay between the two clicks by use `delay` option. The code below will click double clicks to element with 100ms delay.

```
await page.mouse.click(rect.x, rect.y, { clickCount: 2, delay: 100 });
```

Comment: it do double click but its speed is not like real human being that is why its not triggering the double click that is required which ultimately does not add object in the workspace.

Comment: You can use delay like `await page.mouse.click(rect.x, rect.y, { clickCount: 2, delay: 100 });`. to wait 100ms between the two clicks

Comment: Thanks for this, it sent me in the right direction, but it turns out this does not create two clicks. This creates a single click which registers as a click with clickCount: 2. So, to actually do a double-click, we need to call page.mouse.click twice: once with clickCount: 1, and once with clickCount: 2 and delay: 100

Answer (score 4):

You can also just do:

```
await page.click(selector, { clickCount: 2 });
```

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options)